# MYSQL unique field based on another field + auto incriment

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a table having schema:

```
position, location.
```

I want the `position` to be unique to each `location` and also if I change the `position` of an item from 4 to 2, it will change what was at 2 to 3 and what was at 3 to 4.

I have no clue if this is possible and I am fairly new to MYSQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated and if any more info is needed please ask.

`mysql> CREATE TABLE content_main(
    -> content_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> location TEXT,
    -> position INT NOT NULL,
    -> title TEXT,
    -> key_words TEXT,
    -> link TEXT,
    -> body TEXT,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (content_id));`

Location  :    Position      :       Item

page1      :      1          :        item1

page1      :      2          :        item2

page1       :     3          :        item3

page1       :     4          :        item4

page2       :     1         :         item5

page2      :      2          :        item6

page2      :      3         :         item7

page2       :     3        :          item8

In this example item1 and item5 are in the same position but bc they are not on the same page that is ok. Item7 and item8 share a position and this is not ok bc they are on the same page. Also, if I `set position = 2 where item = 4;` I would like item2 to change to position 3 and item3 to change to position 4 automatically.

Comment: The changing of values should be handled in your business logic, possibly including a trigger on the database side.

Comment: can you explain what are the location and position in your application? about updating values do you want it in the database level? it's possible to have a trigger to check after each insert/update, but it won't be efficient.

Comment: I have a bunch of different pages in my website with ULs. The location is the page the item should be on and the position is its position in the list.